# Program to add left diagonal elements in a square matrix

Tags: c#

I'm able to get the output with below code. Can someone check this and suggest the better way if there is any ?

```
static void Main()
    {
        int[,] matrix1 = {
                           { 12,23,22},
                           { 14,5,12},
                           { 70,80,10 }
                        };

        int sumofleftdiagonals = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < matrix1.GetLength(0); i++)

        {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix1.GetLength(0); j++)
            {
                if (i+j==matrix1.GetLength(0)-1)
                {
                    sumofleftdiagonals += matrix1[i, j];
                }
            }

        }

        Console.WriteLine("Sum of Left diagonal Elements is : {0}", sumofleftdiagonals);
    }enter code here
```

Comment: So you're adding 22, 5, and 70? Surely you just want the item at position `[(matrix1.GetLength(0) - i - 1), i]` and a single loop?

Comment: Although most of the code is self-evident on what you are trying to achieve, but you should still post what is the EXACT output you want (so that it leaves no confusion for others). Please see : [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize your code with single `for` loop as below.

```
int length = matrix1.GetLength(0) - 1;            
for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++)
{           
    sumofleftdiagonals += matrix1[i, length - i];           
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear with my question :(. Yes my idea is to add all Left diagonal elements in a 2D array [22+5+70].

Thank you so much for all your suggestions..